# API Gateway performance comparison between Kubernetes and Native. TPS 20% loss

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes.
Last few days, I did performance test for API Gateway to compare both environments, Kubernetes and Native.
I expected to get similar results in both types of tests, but the second test showed a 20% tps loss.

How to stress : RestfulAPI requests through API Gateway.
Env 1 : **Native** (CentOS) - result : approximately **1700 tps**
Evn 2 : **Kubernetes**  - result : approximately **1350 tps**
* Hardware specifications were the same.

I wonder if this is a common result.
In my opinion, 20% is too much loss.

Sorry for my stupid question, but I am confused.

Answer (score 3):

According to [k8s documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/)

> Kubernetes is a portable, extensible, open-source platform for managing containerized workloads and services, that facilitates both declarative configuration and automation. It has a large, rapidly growing ecosystem. Kubernetes services, support, and tools are widely available.
>
> The name Kubernetes originates from Greek, meaning helmsman or pilot.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubernetes) also says:

> Kubernetes (κυβερνήτης, Greek for "governor", "helmsman" or "captain")

Obviously, the captain’s advantages are not in speed but in the predictability of the work of the entire complex system as a whole

k8s strengths are:

- Service discovery and load balancing
- Storage orchestration
- Automated rollouts and rollbacks
- Automatic bin packing
- Self-healing
- Secret and configuration management

As you can see, the performance gain is not mentioned here.

P.S. There is [great comment](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=21047676) on HN discussion about Serverless hype (TL;DR: slowness and costiness):

> It's concerning how typical the hype machine is in IT. I believe Serverless has its place and value. So does Kubernetes or many other *products* that are often discussed on HN.
>
> But let's be clear, we are talking about commercial products and there is a capital interest in *selling* these services to all of us devs and engineers.
>
> So while use cases exists and benefits wait to be reaped, as a consultant I strongly feel that we should be MUCH more insistent in pointing out when a product does not make sense instead of jumping onto the hype train.
>
> I am basically surrounded by "LETS TRANSFORM EVERYTHING TO KUBERNETES THIS WEEK!" exclamations, conferences are basically "DID YOU ALREADY HEAR ABOUT KUBERNETES?" and so on ...
>
> It reminds me of Ruby on Rails, a mature and well-developed framework used by global tech firms (correct me if wrong: Airbnb, ~Stack Overflow~, Github) to handle parts of their backend in 2019. But for half a decade now even tiny companies have been screaming around about *FancyHTTPTechThisYear (tm)* because scale while reporting 1/500th of the traffic of some famous Rails users.
>
> This is not engineering with objectives in mind, it's more akin to the gaming community yelling for a new console.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and I totally agree with above documents and references. I just wondered if **20% tps loss** could be a understandable figure.